# Creating a PostgreSQL sequence to a field (which is not the ID of the record)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord, rails-postgresql

I am working on a Ruby on Rails app. We are using a PostgreSQL database.

There is a table named `scores` with the following columns:

```
Column        | Type
--------------+-----------------------
id            | integer
value         | double precision
ran_at        | timestamp
active        | boolean
build_id      | bigint
metric_id     | integer
platform_id   | integer
mode_id       | integer
machine_id    | integer
higher_better | boolean
job_id        | integer
variation_id  | integer
step          | character varying(255)
```

I need to add a *sequence* to `job_id` (note: there is no model for `job`).

How do I create this sequence?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use [`CREATE SEQUENCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE scores_job_id_seq;  -- = default name for plain a serial
```

Then add a column default to `scores.job_id`:

```
ALTER TABLE scores ALTER COLUMN job_id
SET DEFAULT nextval('scores_job_id_seq');
```

If you want to *"bind"* the sequence to the column (so it is deleted when the column is deleted), also run:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE scores_job_id_seq OWNED BY scores.job_id;
```

All of this can be replaced with using the pseudo data type [**`serial`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) for the column `job_id` to begin with. See:

- [Safely rename tables using serial primary key columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649682/safely-and-cleanly-rename-tables-that-use-serial-primary-key-columns-in-postgres/14651788#14651788)

If your table already has rows, you may want to set the `SEQUENCE` to the next highest value:

```
SELECT setval('scores_job_id_seq', COALESCE(max(job_id), 1)) FROM scores;
```

And, fill in missing (null) serial values in the table (if any):

```
UPDATE scores
SET    job_id = nextval('scores_job_id_seq')
WHERE  job_id IS NULL;
```

- [How to check a sequence efficiently for used and unused values in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684374/how-to-check-a-sequence-efficiently-for-used-and-unused-values-in-postgresql/32686099#32686099)
- [Postgres manually alter sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745051/postgres-manually-alter-sequence/8750984#8750984)
- [How to reset Postgres' primary key sequence when it falls out of sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync/23390399#23390399)

The only remaining difference: a `serial` column is also set to `NOT NULL`. You may or may not want that, too:

```
ALTER TABLE scores ALTER COLUMN job_id SET NOT NULL;
```

**But** you *cannot* just alter the type of an existing `integer`:

```
ALTER TABLE scores ALTER job_id TYPE serial;
```

`serial` is not an actual data type. It's just a notational convenience feature for `CREATE TABLE`.
In Postgres 10 or later consider an `IDENTITY` column instead:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)

Comment: can you do this using ActiveRecord migration?

Comment: @taa have you tried search it? http://stackoverflow.com/q/7606994/1499698

http://stackoverflow.com/q/7820747/1499698

Answer (score 22):

So I figured out how to do this using ActiveRecord migrations on Ruby on Rails. I basically used Erwin's commands and help from [this page](http://msquaredwebsvc.blogspot.com/2013/01/create-postgresql-sequence-for-ruby-on.html) and put them in the migration files. These are the steps:

1.
In the terminal, type:

```
rails g migration CreateJobIdSequence
rails g migration AddJobIdSequenceToScores
```

2.
Edit the migration files as follows:

*20140709181616_create_job_id_sequence.rb* :

```
class CreateJobIdSequence < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE SEQUENCE job_id_seq;
    SQL
  end

  def down
    execute <<-SQL
      DROP SEQUENCE job_id_seq;
    SQL
  end
end
```

*20140709182313_add_job_id_sequence_to_scores.rb* :

```
class AddJobIdSequenceToScores < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      ALTER SEQUENCE job_id_seq OWNED BY scores.job_id;
      ALTER TABLE scores ALTER COLUMN job_id SET DEFAULT nextval('job_id_seq');
    SQL
  end

  def down
    execute <<-SQL
      ALTER SEQUENCE job_id_seq OWNED BY NONE;
      ALTER TABLE scores ALTER COLUMN job_id SET NOT NULL;
    SQL
  end
end
```

3.
Migrate the database. In the terminal type:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: in case you want a string as job_id, just use `to_char(nextval('job_id_seq'), 'JB000000') ` instead of `nextval('job_id_seq')`

Comment: To rollback I had to use `ALTER TABLE scores ALTER COLUMN job_id DROP DEFAULT;` not `SET NOT NULL`