# How to convert primary key from integer to serial?

Tags: postgresql, types, auto-increment, ddl, postgresql-9.3

In a Postgres 9.3 table I have an `integer` as primary key with automatic sequence to increment, but I have reached the maximum for `integer`. How to convert it from `integer` to `serial`?
I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN id SET DATA TYPE bigint;
```

But the same does not work with the data type `serial` instead of `bigint`. Seems like I cannot convert to `serial`?

Comment: "but it doesn'twork" isn't a proper issue explanation.

Comment: @zerkms Sorry, I convertedto bigint but I want to be serial, if there is a difference

Comment: If you've been able to convert your primary key into `bigint` then add a default value of a sequence that the first value would be the greatest value + 1.

Comment: `serial` is 4 bytes and has the same limits as `integer` Reference: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html

Comment: The statement you're using already converted it to a bigint. The only thing missing is adding a sequence as the default value, in the event it's not already there.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`serial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) is a ***pseudo*** data type, not an actual data type. It's an `integer` underneath with some additional DDL commands executed automatically:

1. Create a `SEQUENCE` (with matching name by default).
2. Set the column `NOT NULL` and the default to draw from that sequence.
3. Make the column "own" the sequence.

Details:

- [Safely rename tables using serial primary key columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649682/safely-and-cleanly-rename-tables-that-use-serial-primary-key-columns-in-postgres/14651788#14651788)

A [**`bigserial`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) is the same, built around a `bigint` column. You want `bigint`, but you already achieved that. To transform an existing `serial` column into a `bigserial` (or `smallserial`), all you need to do is `ALTER` the data type of the column. Sequences are generally based on `bigint`, so the same sequence can be used for any `integer` type.

To "change" a `bigint` into a `bigserial` or an `integer` into a `serial`, you just have to do the rest by hand:

- [Creating a PostgreSQL sequence to a field (which is not the ID of the record)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657693/creating-a-postgresql-sequence-to-a-field-which-is-not-the-id-of-the-record/24659884#24659884)

The actual data type is still `integer` / `bigint`. Some clients like pgAdmin will display the data type `serial` in the reverse engineered `CREATE TABLE` script, if all criteria for a `serial` are met.