# Data type "smallserial" in Postgres not highlighted in Visual Studio Code

Tags: sql, postgresql, visual-studio-code, auto-increment, sqldatatypes

I am new to `postgres`, and I am using Visual Studio Code IDE (version 1.62) to write my scripts.

While doing so, I am observing this strange behaviour where VS Code doesn't highlight the data type `smallserial` (2 bytes).

Here is what I see:

[image]

But I know that the script is correct because this query runs successfully. How can I get the proper highlighting here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because `smallserial` (like `serial` or `bigserial`) are not actual data types. See:

- [How to convert primary key from integer to serial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307835/how-to-convert-primary-key-from-integer-to-serial/27309311#27309311)
- [Safely rename tables using serial primary key columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649682/safely-rename-tables-using-serial-primary-key-columns/14651788#14651788)

In Postgres 10 or later, consider an `IDENTITY` column instead. See:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)

If `serial` and `bigserial` are highlighted, but `smallserial` is not, then that's inconsistent and should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks, but then how come VS Code `serial` and `bigserial`, but serial or `smallserial`. All of them are pseudo data types, so why only one is not recognized by VS Code?

Comment: Thst's a bug then. A missing keyword in their list.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I will create an issue on their GitHub repo then.