# How to pass int2 parameter to a stored function?

Tags: postgresql, function, parameters, casting, plpgsql

I have the following function stored in a Postgres 15 database.
I use dbeaver to connect to the database.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema_name.function_name(
    in input_user_id int2
)
RETURNS TABLE(
    column_1 smallint,
    column_2 character varying,
    column_3 character varying,
    column_4 timestamp with time zone,
    column_5 timestamp with time zone,
    column_6 character varying,
    column_7 int2,
    column_8 int2
)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
    return query
    select * 
    from schema_name.table_name
    where table_name.column_5 = input_user_id;
end;
$function$
;
```

If I run the query part directly on dbeaver, I get the expected results:

```
select * from schema_name.table_name where column_5 = 1;
```

If I run the function I get errors:

```
select * from schema_name.function_name(1);
```

> ```
> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function schema_name.function_name(integer) does not exist
> Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> Position: 15
> ```

All of these get me a different error:

```
select * from schema_name.function_name(int2 '1');
select * from schema_name.function_name(1::int2);
select * from schema_name.function_name(1::smallint);
```

> ```
> SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type
> Detail: Returned type text does not match expected type smallint in column 7.
> Where: SQL statement "select * 
>   from schema_name.table_name
>   where table_name.column_5 = input_user_id"
> PL/pgSQL function schema_name.function_name(smallint) line 3 at RETURN QUERY
> ```

I also typecasted to integer and got another error.

What am I doing wrong?

Note, I added the full list of columns since the error mentions the specific columns, but I didn't edited the error messages.

Comment: The second error is clear: your `returns table` does not match the structure of `schema_name.table_name`. You might be better off setting this up as `returns setof schema_name.table_name`: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/FKGKpwy7).

Comment: You are right, i missed that column 6 was text instead of character varying. Silly mistake that has taken me a lo of time. Thanks

Comment: Since there was no real problem I'm inclined to delete the question to reduce clutter on the system, but that would remove the point to you @Zegarek, So I won't do it unles you agree. Thanks again

Comment: I vote against. Now that Erwin’s answer covers this and much more, I’d accept that. Added benefit of `setof` is that the function will always reflect changes to the table, like added/renamed/dropped/altered columns, without you having to maintain it by manually cascading the change: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Vuqpcxm6)

Comment: @PatomaS: Oh, there are plenty of *real* problems here. :)

Comment: As to the `int2` situation, you can also overload if you really want to call it with a numeric literal, without explicit casting or adding quotes: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/TqW9swa4).

Answer (score 3):

There is no implicit cast from `int4` → `int2` (for good reasons).  So you must pass an actual `int2` (`int2 '1'`) or an untyped string literal  (`'1'`). Detailed assessment and more options:

- [ERROR: function ... does not exist and HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751372/error-function-does-not-exist-and-hint-no-function-matches-the-given-name/24771122#24771122)

More problems:

`smallserial` is not an actual data type. You must use `int2` (a.k.a. `smallint`) in `RETURNS TABLE`. See:

- [Data type "smallserial" in Postgres not highlighted in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69873070/data-type-smallserial-in-postgres-not-highlighted-in-visual-studio-code/69873573#69873573)

Don't use `SELECT *` when the function returns a list of columns. Use a matching `SELECT` list.

Use a table alias and table-qualify all column names that might conflict with `OUT` parameters. (All columns listed in `RETURNS TABLE` are `OUT` parameters effectively.)

This would work:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema_name.function_name(input_user_id int2)
  RETURNS TABLE (
         column_1 int2  -- makes no sense: smallserial
       , column_2 varchar
       , column_3 timestamptz
       , column_4 varchar
       , column_5 int2
   )
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT t.column_1, t.column_2, t.column_3, t.column_4, t.column_5 
   FROM   schema_name.table_name t
   WHERE  t.column_5 = input_user_id;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM schema_name.function_name('1');
```

If you truly want to return the whole row as defined by `schema_name.table_name`, use `RETURNS SETOF schema_name.table_name` instead. *Now* it's ok to use `SELECT *` in the function body. Also, fewer naming collisions:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema_name.function_name(input_user_id int2)
  RETURNS SETOF schema_name.table_name
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT *
FROM   schema_name.table_name
WHERE  column_5 = input_user_id;
$func$;
```

Also demonstrating a simpler SQL function, which does the simple job.