# What is the limit of GENERATED { ALWAYS | BY DEFAULT } AS IDENTITY in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sequence, identity

There are `smallserial`, `serial` and `bigserial` numeric data types in PostgreSQL, which have obvious limits to 32767, 2147483647 and 9223372036854775807 respectively.

But what about `GENERATED { ALWAYS | BY DEFAULT } AS IDENTITY`, does it have any restrictions? Or maybe they are computed according to the provided data type (`SMALLINT`, `INT`, `BIGINT`)?

Comment: "*Or maybe they are computed according to the provided data type*" - yes. And the "serial" types work exactly the same way (they aren't real data types  to begin with)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is dependent on column's data type and could be validated using COLUMNS metadata:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(id SMALLINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY);
CREATE TABLE t2(id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY);
CREATE TABLE t3(id BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY);

SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type,
       is_identity, identity_minimum, identity_maximum, *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN('t1','t2','t3');
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1cdf0e033c95b3dfd2a70c9fde743e04)**

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> There are smallserial, serial and bigserial numeric data types in PostgreSQL, ...

Those are not actual *data types* to begin with. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)

> The data types `smallserial`, `serial` and `bigserial` are not true
> types, but merely a notational convenience for creating unique
> identifier columns

The actual data type used is `smallint`, `int` and `bigint`, respectively.

See:

- [How to convert primary key from integer to serial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307835/how-to-convert-primary-key-from-integer-to-serial/27309311#27309311)
- [Safely rename tables using serial primary key columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649682/safely-rename-tables-using-serial-primary-key-columns/14651788#14651788)

All `serial` types draw numbers from an owned `SEQUENCE`, which is based on `bigint`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html#id-1.9.3.81.7)

> Sequences are based on `bigint` arithmetic, so the range cannot exceed
> the range of an eight-byte integer (`-9223372036854775808` to
> `9223372036854775807`).

`IDENTITY` columns do the same, only the `SEQUENCE` is *exclusively* bound to the owning column, which avoids some oddities that serial "types" exhibit.

See:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)