# Issue updating sequences

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-rds, auto-increment

I want to update the sequences for a table in RDS Postgres 11. Tried the following commands but I don't see the changes committed to the db. I even used `commit`.
What am I missing?

```
1.   SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('table1', 'id'), coalesce(max(id),0) + 1, false) FROM table1;

2.   SELECT setval('table1_id_seq', (SELECT COALESCE(max(id), 0) + 1 FROM table1));
     ALTER TABLE table1 ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('table1_id_seq');
```

```
CREATE TABLE public.table1 (
    id serial4 NOT NULL, --default nextval('table1_id_seq'::regclass)  
    account_id int4 NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT table1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id) );
```

`select currval('table1_id_seq')` returns `6`.

Comment: I am not seeing how you are fetching a sequence with `pg_get_serial_sequence` for a column you have not set the sequence for yet? `pg_get_serial_sequence` will only work with a sequence that is 'owned' by a column.  To your question add the table definition for `table1`.

Comment: CREATE TABLE public.table1 (
 id serial4 NOT NULL,   --default nextval('table1_id_seq'::regclass) --select currval('table_id_seq')=6
 account_id int4 NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT table1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
);

Comment: Please read the comments completely. I went ahead and added the table definition to the question as I asked you to do. In any case you either are having copy/paste issues or naming issues. You are referring to the sequence as either `table1_id_seq` or `table_id_seq`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. To your question add the result from `select * from table1_id_seq ;`. Also from `select max(id) from table1;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ...

> don't see the changes committed to the db

... even though you positively committed the transaction (and you are connected to the right database), then I see only two possible explanations.

#### 1. Barking up the wrong tree

In your question, `public.table1` is schema-qualified in the `CREATE TABLE` statement, but not in either of:

> ```
> SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('table1', 'id'), ...
> SELECT setval('table1_id_seq', ...
> ```

If you have another `table1` in another schema that comes before 'public' in the `search_path`, you end up modifying the respective sequence of that table.

Since the factory default in Postgres is `search_path = "$user",public`, the obvious suspect is a table of the same name in the "home" schema of the current role. See:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

**Solution:**
Fix the search path or schema-qualify table and sequence names.

#### 2. Missing privilege

It should be safe to assume your database role has `SELECT` (or even all) privileges on `table1`. But you need separate, additional privileges on the underlying `SEQUENCE` to run `setval()` on it.

You should see an error message for missing privileges, though!
See:

- [Explicitly granting permissions to update the sequence for a serial column necessary?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/71568/3684)

**Solution:**

```
GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCE table1_id_seq TO the_role;  -- your role here
```

Or work with an `IDENTITY` column instead of a `serial` (Postgres 10+), which inherits privileges for the table implicitly. See:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)
- [How to reset Postgres' primary key sequence when it falls out of sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync/23390399#23390399)

Comment: thank you. solution 1 is the fix in my case. I updated the sequences for all other tables in the target db. however, for some tables sequence "last_value" is entirely different than in source table. i can fix it using setval function, but wondering why is this difference in the first place.

Comment: @Falcon: A `serial` column just offers default values. You can override by inserting any values manually - in which case the underlying `SEQUENCE` may fall out of sync. Make sure you understand the nature of `serial` columns: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27309311/939860 An `IDENTITY` column with `GENERATED ALWAYS` disallows that (but can still be overridden).