# Insert Multiple New Rows Into Table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Assume I have following table : **movies** with primary key **movie_id** a consecutive sequences of number starting 1.

```
movie_id | title | year | rating
1          movie1  1988   9
2          movie2  1970   8
3          moive3  2004   5
4          moive4  1999   7
5          moive5  2015   6
```

My goal is to create sequel for movie released before year 1990 at year 2020, the updated table would look like something :

```
movie_id  |       title       | year | rating
1          movie1               1988    9
2          movie2               1970    8
3          moive3               2004    5
4          moive4               1999    7
5          moive5               2015    6
6          moive1: the sequel   2020    9
7          movie2: the sequel   2020    8
```

I know how to get subsquery : movie released before 1990:

```
SELECT *
FROM movies
WHERE year < 1990;
```

But don't how to move on with this.

Here is my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
  movie_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  year INTEGER NOT NULL,
  rating FLOAT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (title,year)) ;
```

Comment: what do you mean by sequence on the table? @Jean-FrançoisSavard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INSERT...SELECT` Method. Then concatenate the string `":the sequel"` in `title`, Lastly, Add the `'2020'` string in `year`. See below:

```
INSERT INTO movies
SELECT 
      title || ': the sequel' AS title,
      '2020' AS year,
      rating 
FROM movies
WHERE year<1990
```

Comment: Thanks , so psql handle keys by default?

Comment: Your welcome. Yes , **PSQL** will handle the auto increment of `movie_id` unless it is configured.

Comment: Actually , it gives me ERROR:  null value in column "movie_id" violates not-null constraint. I will update my table schema in the question.

Comment: Just set your `movie_id` as auto increment.

Comment: We are not allow to change the schema of the table , but I was thinking , since the movie_id is a consecutive number , can we do something like  max(movie_id) + 1?

Comment: You can change the schema of the table using this command:`ALTER TABLE movie ADD COLUMN movie_id  BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY;`

Comment: sorry for the troublesome, this is part of assignment question , which we shouldn't be changing the table schema.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72446/discussion-between-rigel1121-and-boxy).

Comment: Thanks , I solved it by adding a subquery that output a max (movie_id)+1, that does the trick.

Comment: max (movie_id)+1 won't scale well.  Another option would be to add a sequence to the database (not altering the table schema) and `INSERT INTO movies(movie_id, title,year,rating)
SELECT 
      nextval('my_sequence'),
      title || ': the sequel' AS title,
      '2020' AS year,
      rating 
FROM movies
WHERE year<1990`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @pojo-guy, I've edited my answer already. I remove the fields in the insert into which indicates that all the columns will be inserted with some values.

Comment: This is dubious advice, because one cannot simply change an `integer` data type to `serial` or `bigserial`. Detailed explanation and instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657693/creating-a-postgresql-sequence-to-a-field-which-is-not-the-id-of-the-record/24659884#24659884