# What do "constant", "expression", and "sequence" represent in a DEFAULT clause?

Tags: postgresql, ddl

Currently creating my PostgreSQL tables through Postico, and I came across this field for when creating new columns. It is called `DEFAULT` and its default value is `no default`. You can select `constant`, `expression`, and `sequence` as options, though.

What exactly do these mean?

Comment: Have you tried searching the manual for them? It seems pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: I have, but I don't see exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Can you precise what is not clear then? All I can think of is what you can and can not use in the expressions.

Comment: Maybe if you looked in the PostgreSQL documentation under "D" you'd [find something useful](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-default.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual on [`CREATE TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html):

> `DEFAULT` ***default_expr***
>
> The `DEFAULT` clause assigns a default data value for the column whose column definition it appears within. The value is any
> variable-free expression (subqueries and cross-references to other
> columns in the current table are not allowed). The data type of the
> default expression must match the data type of the column.
>
> The default expression will be used in any insert operation that does
> not specify a value for the column. If there is no default for a
> column, then the default is null.

`constant` and `expression` should be clear now. `sequence` is a special feature to make it a `serial` column:

- [Creating a PostgreSQL sequence to a field (which is not the ID of the record)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657693/creating-a-postgresql-sequence-to-a-field-which-is-not-the-id-of-the-record/24659884#24659884)

More details on the page [@mu provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40964891/what-do-constant-expression-and-sequence-represent-in-postgresql/40966753#comment69139822_40964891):

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl.html