# Postgres sequences not attached to tables

Tags: postgresql

Do we have any query providing the sequences which are NOT attached to any of the tables in Postgres?

I would like to attach them back to tables.

Comment: A `sequence` is it's own object there is nothing that requires them to be attached to a table. What makes you think they need to be attached to a table in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Take all sequences that have no dependency on a column:

```
SELECT oid::regclass
FROM pg_class
WHERE relkind = 'S'
EXCEPT ALL
SELECT objid::regclass
FROM pg_depend
WHERE classid = 'pg_class'::regclass
  AND refclassid = 'pg_class'::regclass
  AND refobjsubid <> 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

To attach ("bind") a sequence to a table column:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE my_seq OWNED BY my_table.my_column;
```

See:

- [Creating a PostgreSQL sequence to a field (which is not the ID of the record)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657693/creating-a-postgresql-sequence-to-a-field-which-is-not-the-id-of-the-record/24659884#24659884)